# How to center icon + text on a jquery button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

The buttons I'm creating for a UI consist of an icon plus some text, thus:

```
  [ <icon> Some Text ]
```

I'm using jQuery to create the button, with HTML like this:

```
<button class="myButton" type="button"/>
```

and JavaScript like this:

```
$('.myButton').button({
                    label: "Some Text",
                    icons: {
                        primary: "icon-custom",
                    }
                })
                .css({ width: '85px' });
```

The design team have specified requirements for how it should look, so I need an to have an 85px wide button (I've managed that bit) with a 5 pixel gap between the icon and text, then center the icon+text pair within the button.

Is this possible, and if so, how? I've not been able to figure it out.

It seems that the default is to left-align the icon on the button, then center the text in what's left, but this doesn't look very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant, but should take care of your requirements.

```
$('.myButton').button({
    label: '<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon icon-custom"></span>text',
}).css({
    width: 85
}).find('.ui-icon').css({
    display:'inline-block',
    position:'relative',
    top:4, //top varies depending on button height / font-size, adapt as needed
    marginRight:5
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ByNuC/5/)

This way, the icon is part of the centered text span. You just have to compensate the vertical align.

Comment: That's very cunning and seems to work nicely (I just need to do some tweaking with the vertical positioning). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its bit difficult to center the icon, it can be done if you set `text: false` but then you will only get the button icon, no button text.

But you can do some css trick to get it:

```
.ui-button-icon-primary 
{
   left:5.5em !important;    // default it is 0.5, so it's always on left position...
}​
```

Modify the `left` value based on your requirements.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvw6E/)